# How does SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY related to JVM heap size?

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, apache-spark-standalone

I am running Spark in standalone mode, inside a container. I can set SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY and I can set jvm heap size, but how should I think of them in relation to each other? Does the jvm heap need head room in addition to the spark worker memory? Should they be the same?

Comment: Hi @EMC, if you got clarification for your abv question, please post here

Comment: I guess more specifically, does SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY set the limit for all jvm memory resources that spark will use, or is there other memory use by spark that may exceed that setting that I need to account for.